How to convert MJD time in UTC (only date, no time) in order to make a plot
I have a list of MJD time. I need to convert it in list UTC but only the date (year/month/day) and no time, so a list that I can use to make a plot with time in x-axis.
Thanks
I tried with astropy and the command Time('list',forma='mjd').iso but i have also the time, and I am not able to delete.

I would utilize the subfmt specification to extract only the data and not the time as follows. I created an array of MJD times and then convert them to UTC and derive only the dates as follows
from astropy.time import Time
import numpy as np

mjd_array = np.arange(51545,51550,1)
time_array = Time(mjd_array,format='mjd')

print(time_array.to_value(format='iso', subfmt='date')


This prints the following as output
['2000-01-02' '2000-01-03' '2000-01-04' '2000-01-05' '2000-01-06']

This should cover your use case I believe. Alternatively if I followed what you were doing I would end print this and that will have both date and time
print(time_array.to_value(format='iso')

['2000-01-02 00:00:00.000' '2000-01-03 00:00:00.000'
 '2000-01-04 00:00:00.000' '2000-01-05 00:00:00.000'
 '2000-01-06 00:00:00.000']

